# Django Migrate command throwing ORA-00955 error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oracle, django-models

I have an `oracle 12c` existing database.

I used `inspectdb` to create the django models. Most of the tables in the db dont have a primary key and I assume that if `pk` is not set explicitly, then Django would apply the `id` column as the primary key to the tables.

Also, I have set `managed=True` on all my models so, Django should ideally be able to create the `id` column for its use.

When I run `makemigrations`, I dont get any error. But when I run migrate after that I get the following error:-

```
return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955:
    name is already used by an existing object
```

Any clue why I am getting this error?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant in your case but you might check https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24407.

Comment: I dont think I fully understand the solution. Also it is for pre 1.7, Django I am using is 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:-

So, I found out that the issue was with the initial migration itself. Since, the tables were already existing in my case, it might have taken it as duplicate object names when trying to migrate the first time. I had to fake the initial migration so that it only checks if the tables exist for the models and if it does then migrate. Below is the command for the same. It worked perfectly and my initial migration was successful.

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```